# Combining small Parquet files into bigger Parquet files with Spark fails with OOM Error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I tried to create a script that will combine a lot of small parquet files into less bigger parquet files at around my file system block size.

I am running my code(spark-2.4.3 and scala-2.12.7) on a weak VM, so the files cant fit all at once into memory, disk space is limited and spark is running on local mode.

I thought of this solution:

```scala
  spark.read.parquet(shortFileList:_*)
    .repartition(amountOfNewFiles)
    .write
    .parquet("outDir")
```

and then I got `Out of memory exception` on my executor, and I wasn't sure why, I thought that spark was going to crate a `amountOfNewFiles` Tasks and just execute them one by one but its seems like repartition makes spark read all the small files at the same time.

> Why did repartition cause spark to read all the data into memory, and
>   is there any workaround to get the behavior I expected?

And one more thing after asking a friend for help he came up with this solution:

```scala
  shortFileList
    .tail
    .foldRight(spark.read.parquet(shortFileList.head)){ (newDfName, df) =>
      df.union(spark.read.parquet(newDfName))
    }.write.parquet("outDir")
```

This solution looked weird and I didn't know what to expect of it because the transformation function gets a variable out of his scope, after running it I got an `GC overhead limit exceeded` on my executor which was really weird because the it kept running while tossing those exception over and over instead of 
crashing with an out of memory exception and I had no clue why it did so.

Comment: AFAIK In first case OOM since your `amountOfNewFiles` has not enough you have to further refine your repartition logic. second GC case you have to fine tune GC Parameters in the spark-submit

Comment: Weak VM I would state